# Generalised linear models (for dummies)

Tags: generalized-linear-model

I'm trying to get to grips with this topic, and it's proving tough. Could anyone point me in the direction of some good web based sources to read? I'm looking for good explanations of the theory and also good explanations of how to put it into practice (in R if possible)

Answer (score 2):

This is a self-citation, but I think it is a good match to what you're after:

Dunn, P. K., and Smyth, G. K, (2018). *Generalized linear models with examples in R*. Springer, New York, NY. (Published 11 November 2018)

https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4419-0118-7

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/1441901175](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1441901175)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

**Books:**

[Generalized, Linear, and Mixed Models 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470073713) (a personal favorite of mine)

[Applied Regression Analysis and Generalized Linear Models Third Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1452205663)

[Generalized Linear Models and Extensions, Third Edition 3rd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1597181056)

[Generalized Linear Mixed Models: Modern Concepts, Methods and Applications (Chapman & Hall/CRC Texts in Statistical Science) 1st Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1439815127)

**Online Course Materials:**

[Princeton Course on Generalized Linear Statistical Models by German Rodriguez](https://data.princeton.edu/wws509)

[Iowa State University Course on Linear Models by Dan Nettleton](https://dnett.public.iastate.edu/S511/lectureNotes.shtml) (See Slide Deck 33 in particular)

[Penn State STAT 504 notes](https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat504/node/216/)

[MIT Open Courseware.  Statistics for Applications, Lecture 21](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-ix97pw0xY)